# MongoDB nested collection query of same collection

Tags: mongodb

How do you do a nested query when you need the results of the same collection in the next query?

```
var mongo = require('../config/mongo');

var mongoDB = mongo.db;
...

exports.myFunction = function(req, res) {

...
...
// e.g. myArray = ['a','b','c'];

mongoDB.collection('MyCollection', function(err, collection) {
    collection.find({ $or: [{ 'source': {$in: myArray} },{ 'target': {$in: myArray} }]}, { "someVar": 0}).toArray(function(err, firstResults) {

            var allResults = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < firstResults.length; i++) {
                allResults[firstResults[i].source]=1;
                allResults[firstResults[i].target]=1;
            };

            var secondResults = Object.keys(allResults);

            mongoDB.collection('MyCollection', function(err, collection) {
                collection.find({ $or: [{ 'source': {$in: secondResults} },{ 'target': {$in: secondResults} }]}, { "someVar": 0}).toArray(function(err, items) {
                    res.send(items);
                });
            });


    });
});
```

But it doesn't like that I am calling the same collection 'MyCollection' twice. I'm trying to get any document whose source or target involves secondResults.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should get rid of the second call to open 'MyCollection'. You already have a 'MyCollection' object after opening it once. Namely, you have this:

```
mongoDB.collection('MyCollection', function(err, collection) {
  collection.find({ $or: [{ 'source': {$in: secondResults} },{ 'target': {$in: secondResults} }]}, { "someVar": 0}).toArray(function(err, items) {
    res.send(items);
   });
});
```

but you already have an instance of 'MyCollection' from here:

```
mongoDB.collection('MyCollection', function(err, collection) {
  collection.find({ $or: [{ 'source': {$in: myArray} },{ 'target': {$in: myArray} }]}, { "someVar": 0}).toArray(function(err, firstResults) {
```

So since the second call to 'collection' is in the scope of the first call, you can (and should) reuse that instance:

```
collection.find({ $or: [{ 'source': {$in: secondResults} },{ 'target': {$in: secondResults} }]}, { "someVar": 0}).toArray(function(err, items) {
  res.send(items);
});
```

Alternatively, if you're using [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native), you can have a look at [some of the examples](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/1.4/examples/blog.js) to see other ways of accomplishing what you're after.

### UPDATE 1

This code works for me:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db){
  if(err) throw err;

  var collection = db.collection('c');
  var secondQuery = {};

  collection.find({a:'b'}).toArray(function(err, firstRes){
    for(var i = 0; i < firstRes.length; i++){
      secondQuery[firstRes[i].a] = firstRes[i].b;
    }

    collection.find(secondQuery).toArray(function(err, secondRes){
      for(var i = 0; i < secondRes.length; i++){
        console.log(secondRes[i]);
      }

      db.close();
    });
  });
});
```

### UPDATE 2

Note that the above code is using [node-mongodb-native version 1.3.19](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/tree/V1.3.19). Since version 1.2, [it is recommended to use MongoClient](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html) when interacting with mongodb from Node.js driver.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I tried replacing the second: mongoDB.collection('MyCollection', function(err, collection) {  with just the collection.find({ but I am getting the same error. How is it the same scope if I am inside the .toArray(function(err, firstResults) {} success function?

Comment: Hmm, I added a code sample that works for me. Which mongodb driver are you using?

Comment: I'm using mongodb module and I connect to it with: var mongo = require('../config/mongo');

var mongoDB = mongo.db;     -thanks!

Comment: There are many mongodb modules. Are you running this code with Node.js? If so, the supported mongodb javascript driver is the node-mongodb-native driver that I mentioned in my answer. Do you have a link to the page where you downloaded your driver?

Comment: Yep I'm using node! So in my server.js I set up a mongo store MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express)   and in my app.configure i have     app.use(express.session({
        store: new MongoStore({url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/..'}),
        secret: '...'
    })),

Comment: To answer your other question, I am using the native db driver

Comment: Based on your previous comment, it looks like you are using connect-mongo (https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo). That module is for storing sessions in mongodb. Is that what you're using it for?

Comment: I do use that for sessions (for user login etc) but the route in question i use this: var mongo = require('../config/mongo'); var mongoDB = mongo.db;          where my config file looks like this: var mongo = require('mongodb');

var Server = mongo.Server,
    Db = mongo.Db,
    BSON = mongo.BSONPure;

var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true});
var db = new Db('mydb', server, {safe: true});

db.open(function(err, db) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("Connected to database");
    }
});

module.exports = {    
    db: db,
    BSON: BSON
}

Comment: In your example, if you could define how you specify your "db" that may help too.

Comment: Quite right. I've added the connection code and the driver version I'm using (1.3.19).

Comment: Sorry but I tried to use your method and after npm install mongodb I still get an error "MongoClient is not defined" or the other syntax I get "Cannot call method 'connect' of undefined"

Comment: Ok! I found out this was a problem with my version! I went and got your version and this approach worked! Thanks for your perseverance!

Comment: Phew! Glad we figured that out!